# Zend_Db: How to get the number of rows from a table?

Tags: mysql, zend-framework, zend-db-table

I want to find out how many rows are in a table. The database that I am using is a MySQL database. I already have a Db_Table class that I am using for calls like `fetchAll()`. But I don't need any information from the table, just the row count. How can I get a count of all the rows in the table without calling `fetchAll()`?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
$count = $db->fetchOne( 'SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM yourTable' );
```

Answer (score 8):

Counting rows with `fetchAll` considered harmful.

Here's how to do it the Zend_Db_Select way:

```
$habits_table = new Habits(); /* @var $habits_table Zend_Db_Table_Abstract */
$select = $habits_table->select();
$select->from($habits_table->info(Habits::NAME), 'count(*) as COUNT');
$result = $habits_table->fetchRow($select);
print_r($result['COUNT']);die;
```

Comment: Why do you say "Counting rows with fetchAll is considered harmful"?

Answer (score 5):

Proper Zend-Way is to use Zend_Db_Select like this:

```
$sql = $table->select()->columns(array('name', 'email', 'status'))->where('status = 1')->order('name');
$data = $table->fetchAll($sql);
$sql->reset('columns')->columns(new Zend_Db_Expr('COUNT(*)'));
$count = $table->getAdapter()->fetchOne($sql);
```

This is how it's done in Zend_Paginator. Other option is to add `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` before your column list and then get the number of found rows with this query:

```
$count = $this->getAdapter()->fetchOne('SELECT FOUND_ROWS()');
```

Comment: it's Zend_Db_Table instance. Or it can be Zend_Db_Adapter as well. The metod is in both. It returns Zend_Db_Table_Rowset for DbTable and array for Adapter...

Comment: This answer is particularly useful if you need to count the results of a contrived query that you have lost the original result set for... +1

Answer (score 3):

You could do a

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM your_table
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$dbo->setFetchMode( Zend_Db::FETCH_OBJ );
$sql = 'SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM @table';
$res = $dbo->fetchAll( $sql );
// $res[0]->count contains the number of rows
```

Answer (score 2):

Add count capability to your Zend_DB Object To count all table rows

```
public function count()
{
    return (int) $this->_table->getAdapter()->fetchOne(
        $this->_table->select()->from($this->_table, 'COUNT(id)')
    );
}
```

Comment: Read again, the question wasn't about filtering!

Comment: Ah. Sorry :( If you edit your answer (single character will do) I'd be able to revert the downvote... :)

Comment: ;) Thanks! Zend conformity does need be addressed :)

Comment: My version of the Zend table doesn't know fetchOne() but it knows fetchRow(). I don't understand why this answer doesn't have any upvote. It is indeed the way to go using the framework.

Answer (score 2):

I'm kind of a minimalist:

```
public function count()
{
    $rows = $db->select()->from($db, 'count(*) as amt')->query()->fetchAll();
    return($rows[0]['amt']);
}
```

Can be used generically on all tables.